# repeating in df with function python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, while-loop

I have this df where in the Order column if greater than 0 results in long, if less than 0 results in short. I would like to create a column that calculates the result of profit or loss when the criterion is the pre-established gain and loss limit in the tp and sl variables.

```
list_1 = [26.66, 26.7, 26.72, 26.73, 26.74, 26.88, 26.63, 26.56, 26.51, 26.55, 26.54, 26.5, 26.52, 26.59, 26.43, 26.46, 
          26.54, 26.51, 26.54, 26.5, 26.51, 26.47, 26.48, 26.41, 26.4, 26.37]
list_2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]



df = pd.DataFrame({
    'close': list_1,
    'Ordem': list_2})

sl = 0.02
tp = 0.03


#long
if df['Ordem'] > 0: = x
    #take profit
    if df['Close']> x+tp:
        return df['Close'] - x
    #stop loss
    else df['Close']< x-sl:
        return df['Close'] - x    
or

#short
if df['Ordem'] < 0: = y
    #take profit
    if df['Close']< y-tp:
        return y - df['Close']
    #stop loss
    else df['Close']>y+sl:
        return y - df['Close']
```

Comment: The latter part of your code doesn't seem like runnable python code, for example, `if df['Ordem'] > 0: = x` doesn't have proper syntax. What exactly are x and y? Please provide more details.

Comment: Correct, it is not executable python code. just a code project where x would be the value of the next column at the time when df['Order'] =! 0. In this case x = 26.51 and Y = 26.54.